# Spring Tool Suite (STS) 3.5.0 - org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse is unknown in the solver

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, spring-tool-suite

There is a problem with STS 3.5.0

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3792

org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse 2.9.0.xx-201403261719-e43j8 is unknown in the solver!

These are the steps I took to fix it and it allowed me to use eclipse marketplace

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Help -> Check for updates
>
> Problem Occured
>
> "JDT Core patch with Java 8 Support for Groovy-Eclipse plugin" is not
>   applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed.
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Searching alternate solutions...".
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse 2.9.0.xx-201403261719-e43j8 is unknown in
>   the solver!

If you get this error, then these are the steps to fix it:

> Help
>
> About Spring Tool Suite
>
> Installation Details
>
> Eclipse Java Development Tools Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler
>   SR2)
>
> Uninstall...
>
> restart

Then to verify that the error is gone:

> Help -> Check for updates
>
> No updates were found.

It should be ok now. But you need to install the Java 8 support

Then follow these steps:

> Help
>
> Install new software...
>
> Work with: SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.3 -
>   http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3
>
> [x] Groovy-Eclipse
>
> Next
>
> Next
>
> I accept
>
> Finish
>
> Restart

That should do it.

Comment: This seems to have worked perfectly -- much appreciated. I filed a bug against STS 3.5.0 to no avail so far. Thanks.

Comment: Still buggy with STS 3.5.1, I hope this will go away on the next release.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that too: I upgraded to 3.5.1 yesterday and saw that it was still having an issue, so decided to search and see if anyone had come up with a real workaround/solution and found this. Hopefully they get it all sorted out. Apparently it was kind of a workaround they had to do to get Java 8 support working with the update sites.

Comment: This issue was still happening for me with 3.6.0 and this answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Check if groovy-eclipse is installed. If it is not, then you need to install it first then install STS.

Check this website for installation https://www.function1.com/2016/06/installing-eclipse-groovy-plugin