# Error while updating eclipse: Searching Alternate solutions

Tags: eclipse, groovy, spring-tool-suite

Eclipse is throwing the following error when I check for updates:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Searching alternate solutions...".
org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse 2.6.1.xx-20120301-1300-e36-RELEASE is unknown in the solver!
```

I have searched and checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406047/spring-tool-suite-sts-3-5-0-org-codehaus-groovy-eclipse-is-unknown-in-the-so) related question, but I do not have the mentioned package installed. Neither anything is getting listed when I search for groo/java 8 etc in the installed software.

If I just ignore the groovy plugin update listed (and marked in error), and try to continue with the update, I am getting below error while updating software:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.codehaus.jackson.core,1.9.13
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.codehaus.jackson.mapper,1.9.13
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.0.0.v20110215-1551
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.roo.wrapping.protobuf-java-lite,2.3.0.0001
```

Eclipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0) and Build id: 20160613-1800

How do I fix this?

---

Installation Details from Eclipse:

```
Ansi Console    1.3.1.201508091828  net.mihai-nita.ansicon.feature.group    Mihai Nita
Axis2 Tools 1.1.301.v201410160332   org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Cloud Foundry Tools Core    1.0.4.v201606021906 org.eclipse.cft.server.core.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry
Cloud Foundry Tools UI  1.0.3.v201606021906 org.eclipse.cft.server.ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry
Code Recommenders for Java Developers   2.4.0.v20160607-1609    org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Code Recommenders
Code Recommenders Mylyn Integration 2.4.0.v20160607-1609    org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Code Recommenders
CXF Web Services    1.1.203.v201503151903   org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - Common    1.5.0.v201603181811 org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink Common    1.3.200.v201603180253   org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink DBWS Support  1.2.200.v201603180253   org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JAXB Support  1.4.200.v201603180253   org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support   3.4.100.v201603180253   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - JAXB Support  1.5.100.v201603180253   org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Support   3.5.0.v201603181811 org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Connectivity    1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Connectivity Documentation  1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Enablement  1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Intro   1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.intro.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Model Base  1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform SQL Dev Tools Documentation 1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.doc.user.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools   1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform Tutorial Documentation  1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.common.doc.user.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Data Tools Platform User Documentation  1.13.0.201603142002 org.eclipse.datatools.doc.user.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
Docker Tooling  2.0.0.201606101757  org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.feature.feature.group Eclipse Linux Tools
EclEmma Java Code Coverage  2.3.3.201602231923  com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature.feature.group Mountainminds GmbH & Co. KG
Eclipse Faceted Project Framework   3.7.0.v201505072140 org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement    3.8.0.v201603091933 org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse Git Team Provider   4.4.0.201606070830-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
Eclipse Git Team Provider - Task focused interface  4.4.0.201606070830-r    org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse EGit
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  4.6.0.20160613-1800 epp.package.jee Eclipse Packaging Project
Eclipse Java Development Tools  3.12.0.v20160606-1100   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.8.0.v201605251556 org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools    3.8.0.v201605120129 org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment 3.12.0.v20160606-1100   org.eclipse.pde.feature.group   Eclipse.org
Eclipse Quicksearch 3.8.0.201606300730-RELEASE  org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch.feature.feature.group  Pivotal Software, Inc.
Eclipse VJET JavaScript IDE (Incubation)    0.10.0.201303191704 org.eclipse.vjet.js.ide.feature.group   Eclipse.org
Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.8.0.v201606030549 org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools   3.8.0.v201605120129 org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Eclipse XSL Developer Tools 1.3.401.v201509231858   org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
EditBox 0.70.0.201508180438 pm.eclipse.editbox.feature.feature.group    Nodeclipse
JavaScript Development Tools    2.0.0.v201605311817 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JavaScript Development Tools Chromium/V8 Remote Debugger    0.4.0.v201606032110 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JAX-WS DOM Tools    1.0.302.v201504272154   org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JAX-WS Tools    1.2.203.v201602092125   org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Jeeeyul's Themes    2.3.0.I20151022-090442  net.jeeeyul.eclipse.themes.feature.feature.group    Jeeeyul@gmail.com
JSF Tools   3.9.0.v201605262035 org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JSF Tools - Tag Library Metadata (Apache Trinidad)  2.6.0.v201410101748 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JSF Tools - Web Page Editor 2.8.0.v201605262035 org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JSHint Eclipse Integration  0.10.1.20160216-0911    com.eclipsesource.jshint.feature.feature.group  EclipseSource
JST Server Adapters 3.2.400.v201606081655   org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JST Server Adapters Extensions  3.3.500.v201603031514   org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
JST Server UI   3.4.300.v201606081655   org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
LiClipseText Feature    1.0.0.201605191643  org.brainwy.liclipsetext.feature.feature.group  Brainwy Software Ltda
m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)    1.7.0.20160603-1933 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.7.0.20160603-1933 org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
m2e-wtp - JAX-RS configurator for WTP (Optional)    1.3.0.20160530-2310 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional)   1.3.0.20160530-2310 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
m2e-wtp - JSF configurator for WTP (Optional)   1.3.0.20160530-2310 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.3.0.20160530-2310 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
Markdown Editor 1.2.0.201501260515  markdown.editor.feature.feature.group   Winterwell
Minimalist Jade Editor  1.0.2.201509250223  org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.jade.feature.feature.group Nodeclipse/Enide
MoreUnit For Java   3.1.1   org.moreunit.feature.group  MoreUnit.org
MoreUnit For Java: Mock Support 3.1.1   org.moreunit.mock.feature.group MoreUnit.org
MoreUnit Light  3.1.1   org.moreunit.light.feature.group    MoreUnit.org
Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE    3.20.0.v20160421-1902   org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Context Connector: Java Development   3.20.0.v20160421-1902   org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Task List 3.20.0.v20160608-1838   org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Task-Focused Interface    3.20.0.v20160608-1905   org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Tasks Connector: Bugzilla 3.20.0.v20160425-1835   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn WikiText  2.9.0.v20160601-1831    org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
Nodeclipse ChromeDevTools SDK   0.3.9.201509250223  org.chromium.sdk.feature.group  The Chromium Authors, Nodeclipse
Nodeclipse Chromium JavaScript Remote Debugger  0.3.9.201509250223  org.chromium.debug.feature.group    The Chromium Authors, Nodeclipse
Nodeclipse Core and Node.js 1.0.2.201509250223  org.nodeclipse.feature.group    Nodeclipse/Enide
Nodeclipse Git Addon    1.0.0.20140303-0606 gitaddon.feature.feature.group  Nodeclipse organization
Nodeclipse Plugins List 1.0.2.201509250223  org.nodeclipse.pluginslist.feature.feature.group    Nodeclipse organization
Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime 3.7.1.201603211627  org.eclipse.rse.feature.group   Eclipse TM Project
Remote System Explorer User Actions 3.7.0.201603211627  org.eclipse.rse.useractions.feature.group   Eclipse TM Project
SonarLint for Eclipse   2.1.0.20160603-1122-RELEASE org.sonarlint.eclipse.feature.feature.group SonarSource
SonarLint for Eclipse Java Configuration Helper 2.1.0.20160603-1122-RELEASE org.sonarlint.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group SonarSource
Spring IDE AOP Extension (optional) 3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Autowire Extension (optional)    3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.autowire.feature.feature.group  Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Batch Extension (optional)   3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.batch.feature.feature.group Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Boot Microservices Dash  3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature.feature.group Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Core (required)  3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension (optional)  3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Maven Support    3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Security Extension (optional)    3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.feature.feature.group  Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Spring Data Support  3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.feature.feature.group  Spring IDE Developers
Spring IDE Web Flow Extension (optional)    3.8.0.201606301005-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
StartExplorer  Feature  1.7.0   de.bastiankrol.startexplorer.feature.feature.group  Bastian Krol
SWTend  2.2.5.I20140918-144458  net.jeeeyul.swtend.feature.feature.group    jeeeyul@gmail.com
TM Terminal 4.1.0.201606052351  org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - Target Management
WST Server Adapters 3.2.500.v201606081655   org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
```

Comment: do you have any concrete steps how to reproduce this problem? Looks like you have specific additional plugins installed (like Groovy-Eclipse)

Comment: Groovy-Eclipse is not installed. I tried installing it, to check if installing-uninstalling groovy eclipse fixes this issue, but that too failed. Updated the question with list of plugins installed.

Comment: Maybe a problem with stale update site data... Try to delete all the update sites from the preferences, restart STS, and add them back, step by step to see when the error starts to appear. This is at least the only idea that I have in mind at the moment.

Comment: @MartinLippert Awesome, that worked. I disabled all, got the message as 'no update sites' and while adding them back I found 3 entries for 'SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 3.6' (additional one for 4.5), and turns out they were the culprit. The error also vanished when I updated apps in chunks; it occurred only when I was installing all the  apps in the long list in one go. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: glad to hear that. and sure, posted as an answer.

Comment: @NikhilWanpal could you please post disabling `SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 3.6` as an answer. It worked for me.

Comment: @dlopatin It was merely a step in Martin's answer. Please upvote the same answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to delete all the update sites from the preferences, restart STS, and add them back, step by step to see when the error starts to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any 'SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse x.x' that doesn't match your version

Answer (score -2):

I updated eclipse and the probleme was solved